# Run query function if screen size is this or that

Tags: jquery, media-queries, bxslider

hoping someone can help.

I'm creating a responsive version of my website and am having issues with the featured work slider. Its using the bxSlider plugin.

I've the below function which worlds great, however I need to be able to change the slideWidth option for when an iPhone is in landscape mode. I've tried everything I can via CSS to no avail. Reading the documentation it also states that slideWidth is required for horizontal sliders - which mine is.

Any help would be appreciated...

```
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  minSlides: 1,
  maxSlides: 3,
  slideWidth: 310,
  slideMargin: 20,
  useCSS: false,
  hideControlOnEnd: true,
  infiniteLoop: false,
  easing: 'easeOutBounce',
  speed: 1000,
  nextSelector: '#slider-next',
  prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
  nextText: '>',
  prevText: '<',
  pager: false
});
```

---

Please note: I have tried the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

// Variable to detect window width.
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

// Trigger function for a certain window width
if (windowWidth<568) {
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      minSlides: 1,
      maxSlides: 3,
      slideWidth: XXX,
      slideMargin: 20,
      useCSS: false,
      hideControlOnEnd: true,
      infiniteLoop: false,
      easing: 'easeOutBounce',
      speed: 1000,
      nextSelector: '#slider-next',
      prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
      nextText: '>',
      prevText: '<',
      pager: false
    }); 
     }
});
```

But the main issue is that I still need to run the function on all screen sizes, it's just the slideWidth property that needs to change. Surely there's a way of just changing that to make it some sort of variable? I'm not sure if that's the right term, I'm still learning jQuery.

Comment: Are you just looking for `screen.width` and `screen.height`?

Comment: Well, I think the solution above would target the iPhone in landscape mode HOWEVER am I right in just repeating the function? It seems a very clumsy workaround to me

Comment: If you're targeting iPhones specifically, don't use screen width.

Comment: You need to get the window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight values, then to listen to the window.onresize event

Comment: Thank you for your comment and example, I'll try it out. OUt of interest, I've just stumbled across this - would this do what I'm after? http://css-tricks.com/enquire-js-media-query-callbacks-in-javascript/

Comment: Yes, this would do the job too.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  var w = $(window).width();
  var x = // calculate box Slider width depending on w
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    ...
    slideWidth: x,
    ...
  });
  $(window).resize(function(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    // whatever function to resize your slider if the window is resized (will work if the phone is turned)
});
```